# How can I find a number whose sum of digits' cube is equal to n

Tags: algorithms, number-theory

I'm given a number $n$ and I have to find the smallest number possible whose sum of digits' cube is equal to $n$. For example $n=9$ then output should be $12$, because $1^3 + 2^3=9$.

Comment: Another solution would be $111111111$. This one can be easily generalized. Are you trying to find the *shortest* solution?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes the smallest number possible

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? You will learn by solving it yourself, not relying on someone else to solve it for you.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider the more general problem in which we fix integers $0 < a_1 < \cdots < a_m$, and then given a positive integer $n$, we want to determine the *smallest* non-negative integer combination $\sum_{i=1}^m d_i a_i$ which is equal to $n$, if any exists, or determine the none exists. Here one combination $(d_1,\ldots,d_m)$ is smaller than another $(e_1,\ldots,e_m)$ if either $d_1+\cdots+d_m < e_1+\cdots+e_m$, or $d_1+\cdots+d_m = e_1+\cdots+e_m$ and for some $i$ we have $d_1=e_1,\ldots,d_{i-1}=e_{i-1}$ and $d_i > e_i$.

The main observation is that any optimal solution satisfies $d_i < a_m$ for all $i < m$. Indeed, if $d_i \geq a_m$ then we can decrease $d_i$ by $a_m$ and increase $d_m$ by $a_i$ to obtain a better solution. (In fact, this shows that $d_i < \mathrm{lcm}(a_i,a_m)/a_i$.) This suggests the following algorithm:

> Go over all possible values of $d_1,\ldots,d_{m-1}$ such that $0 \leq d_1,\ldots,d_{m-1} < a_m$. For each such setting, check whether it can be completed to a solution, that is, whether $a_m$ divides $n-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} d_i a_i$. Choose the smallest solution, if any exists.

This algorithm runs in time $O(\log n)$, where the hidden constant depends in some horrible way on $a_1,\ldots,a_m$. This is optimal (up to the value of the hidden constant) since clearly we need to read the entire input.

---

The algorithm above doesn't really help you solve your case in practice, since the hidden constant is too large. Presumably you were supposed to use dynamic programming, an algorithm which runs in time $O(n)$ and finds the minimal length of a solution (perhaps it can also be tweaked to find a solution of minimal value).

Answer (score 2):

The smallest number producing n always consists of the digits 1 to 9, in non-decreasing order. Fill an array with the smallest number producing n, for n = 0, 1, 2, 3, .... I bet you will be able to show that for some N, the smallest number to produce n ≥ N consists of producing n - 729, followed by a digit 9.

Actually, the last number where this is not the case is n = 9*512 + 1 = 4609 which is the sum of digit cubes of 1888888888. For every n ≥ 4610, the smallest number with sum of digit cubes = n is the solution for n - 729, followed by the digit 9.

So finding the solution as a decimal number requires O (n) because the size of the solution is O (n) (about n/729 digits), but describing it in the form a * 10^k - b can be done in O (log n).